# ARC, between block and C callback

Tags: objective-c, c

I've a c function which takes a callback function as one parameter, I'm going to write an Obj-C wrapper to a standard C API. I would like to replace C callbacks by blocks.

Let's imagine a C API:

```
void audioStopFunction(void (*callback)(void *), void *udata);
```

The Obj-C wrapper looks like this:

```
- (void)myAudioStopFunction:(dispatch_block_t)block
{
    void *udata = (__bridge void *)block;
    audioStopFunction(my_callback, udata);
}

void my_callback(void *udata)
{
    dispatch_block_t block = (__bridge_transfer dispatch_block_t)udata;
    block();
}
```

Now, I have some questions:

1. In `myAudioStopFunction` function, do i need to copy the block like below:

   > void *udata = (__bridge void *)[block copy];
2. In `my_callback` function, should i use `__bridge` instead of `__bridge_transfer`? And also, do i need to call `Block_release` after `block()`?
3. Will the code cause memory leak? if yes, then what's the correct way?

Comment: Are you calling `audioStopFunction` only from `myAudioStopFunction`? Asked in another way: Is the class that implements `myAudioStopFunction` the (single) owner of the C callback?

Comment: yes, it is the owner of the c callback. `myAudioStopFunction` is in a class, this class is a singletion class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the C callback is managed by the wrapper class it's most easy to let the class manage the ownership of the block. (I'm calling the block `completionBlock`, as this seems to be a bit more in line with Cocoa naming conventions.)

```
@interface AudioCallbackWrapper
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_block_t completionBlock;
@end

static void my_callback(void *udata)
{
    dispatch_block_t block = (__bridge dispatch_block_t)udata;
    if (block != nil)
        block();
}

@implementation AudioCallbackWrapper
- (void)setCompletionBlock:(dispatch_block_t)completionBlock
{
    _completionBlock = [completionBlock copy];
    audioStopFunction(my_callback, (__bridge void *)_completionBlock);
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    // remove the C callback before completionBlock is released
    self.completionBlock = nil;
}
@end
```

Since the block's lifetime is managed by the enclosing wrapper, the C code never has to transfer ownership. So the code only contains `__bridge` casts to and from a `void *`.

> Will the code cause memory leak? if yes, then what's the correct way?

Your original code would release the block every time the callback fires. The block pointer would dangle after the first callback.

Comment: Given this is a single shot object, I think you should pass the completion block in the initialiser and make the property read only.  Also, with ARC, your dealloc method is redundant.

Comment: @JeremyP It might still be valuable to be able to change the callback. Also, even with ARC, the `dealloc` performs necessary cleanup and is definitely not redundant: ARC would just release the `completionBlock` but leave the C callback parameter in place.

Comment: @JeremyP It might be a good idea to make the wrapper class a singleton, though, as the C callback seems to be global. Then the `dealloc` would indeed be redundant.

Comment: Shouldn't the block be declared with copy semantics: `@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t completionBlock;`?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe The C callback is global, but the block is not.  If you maker the object a singleton you can never change the callback, or at least you would have to ensure that the previous call to `audioStopFunction` was done before you changed it.

Comment: @JeremyP Not sure if I'm getting you. Anyway: The C callback is global. It stores `udata` somewhere global (static storage duration). As it stores just a `void *` one has to make sure that the block's lifetime is longer than the callback keeps the `void *` around. That's the main sense of the wrapper class and the reason for setting the callback's `udata` to `NULL` from `dealloc`. Controlling the lifetime of the block would easily be achieved by making the class a singleton. To make the callback changeable, `completionBlock` must be `readwrite`.

Comment: @i_am_jorf You're right. Marking the property `copy` would be more correct (even though behavior under ARC is the same).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe The callback is global, but all it does is execute a block that was passed to `audioStopFunction` as user data.  If I want to call `audioStopFunction` a second time with a different completion handler before the completion handler of the first call has executed, I should use two instances of `AudioCallbackWrapper`.  Otherwise the second call will overwrite the pointer to the first block which will then leak.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm understanding the OP as: `audioStopFunction` is a C function that *sets* a global callback for some 3rd party audio lib. It takes a function pointer (the actual callback) and a user defined `void *`. With this setup it's impossible to have several clients waiting for the callback at the same time. If needed this has to be implemented in client code (the wrapper) but it's not part of the question. As you said, the callback is global and so the block has to be retained as long as nobody changes the callback by calling `audioStopFunction` again.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm sorry, but maybe I'm really not getting what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe my understanding is that `audioStopFunction` performs some function asynchronously and then calls the completion handler to notify the caller that it has finished.  That is the way callbacks normally work.  If you want to call `audioStopFunction` twice with different completion handlers, you should use two instances of `AudioCallbackWrapper`.  It's a cleaner design.

Comment: @JeremyP If that's the semantics of `audioStopFunction` it's much easier to not use a wrapper at all and instead pass the block using `(__bridge_retained)` into `audioStopFunction` and `(__bridge_transfer)` when the callback fires.

Comment: @JeremyP I do know a lot of crappy C interfaces that do not implement these semantics, though. There are a lot of libraries that just handle a single, global callback.